# sql table update problem

Tags: sql

table 1(ob): name,address

table 2(address): dname,addr

I need to update `ob.address` with `address.addr` when `ob.name=address.dname`. Can anyone help to get better results because I'm using following command which leads system halt.

**UPDATE ob  LEFT JOIN address ON ob.name =address.dname SET ob.address=address.addr;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update ob
set address = address_table.addr
where ob.name = address_table.dname
```

EDIT: Advice: use a better name for Table 2 than address. Maybe TBL_ADDRESS? In my above example I used address_table.

Comment: should be address.addr instead of table2.address (more distinct naming would help the OP a lot here).

Comment: yes, only just noticed the poor naming conventions used for the tables and fields in the question :). Amended.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ob
SET ob.address = address.addr
WHERE ob.name = address.dname
```